COMPUTING a^b % 1e9+7
while computing the question a^b mod 1000000007 for large range of inputs. The major flaw is Integer Overflow after avoiding this we may get stuck by some modular operations So My code unable to resolve some edge cases.
`
public class Solution {
    protected static final int mod=(int)(1e9+7);
     public static List<Integer> cal_setBits(int num) {
        List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        int position = 0;

        while (num > 0) {
            if ((num & 1) == 1) {
                positions.add(position);
            }
            position++;
            num = num >> 1;
        }

        return positions;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0)
        {
            int n1=sc.nextInt();
            int n2=sc.nextInt();
             // using modular exponential
            int arr[]=new int[33];
            // store set-bits
            int count=1;
            int index=1;
             List<Integer> list=cal_setBits(n2);
            arr[0]=n1;
            // int count=1;
            while(count<n2)
            {
                arr[index]=(int)(arr[index-1] *arr[index-1])%mod;
                count*=2;
                index++;
            }
            long res=1;
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                res=(long)(res*arr[list.get(i)]*1l)%mod;
            }
                    System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}

Can anyone explain what's wrong with the code.
Make the code correct

If you already know "The major flaw is Integer Overflow" then why do you keep using int?

1e9 * 1e9 will not fit in int, you may have to go long

If you want to increase the likelihood that someone will "make the code correct", you should provide some testcases with expected results. Ideally hardcoded as a [mre].

That *1l at one point looks like an attempt to use 64-bit integers in that place, which is the right idea but it wasn't done quite right (there are still 32-bit products being done, which are still overflowing)

Are you doing this as an exercise? If you're trying to do this for a production application, you should be using the well-proven existing feature, BigInteger.modPow.

"Can anyone explain what's wrong with the code."  If you could explain or point to the algorithm and explain some of the values (e.g. t) then you may be able to get some assistance.
